# How do I execute command from grep in while loop?

Tags: bash

I need the `do` command to execute if there are matches found with `grep`. This is what I have, but it is not working.

```
while 
tail -F /home/user/log/test.txt | stdbuf -o0 grep -E -A 1 'NDC003|FLC133' | stdbuf -o0 grep 'TO.W'; 
do
cat /home/user/test/turnon.sh | ssh pi@10.10.10.10 bash
done
```

Even though the `grep` returns with matches, the `cat` command does not run. I need the command to run and the `tail -F` to continue monitoring the log file for future pattern matches. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You use `tail -F` to feed your pipe. Therefore, the pipe does not close (unless someone deletes test.txt), and hence your greps do not terminate.

Comment: so how would I continue the `tail -F` and feed that output into the pipe?

Comment: You can feed it to the pipe. You just can't get the exit code of a program before the program ends. A `while COMMAND; do ...done` executes _COMMAND_ repeatedly, until the command returns a non-zero exit code. In your case, you start the command once, and it does never end. It is not clear to me what the while-loop then is supposed to do.

Comment: A while loop might not be the best way to do this. I just need to keep `tail -F` going while executing the command if a match is found.

Comment: Since the input does not terminate, you can not predict whether another match will or will not be found in the future. This would require divination. Hence "while doing something if a match is found" doesn't make sense. What would make sense is to run another command **for every match**, but for this, you don't need a loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it the below way :

```
tail -f /home/user/log/test.txt  | while read line
do case "$line" in
        *"text_to_search"*) <do something>
         ;;
   esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With this construction, a `tail` in the while line, there is only one test on the exit code (of last grep in your case). Except that in your case the process is blocked because `tail -F` never exits.

You can process line by line in a while loop with a construction like in 
funkyjelly answer or in my solution:

```
while read line
do
    ssh pi@10.10.10.10 "bash -s" < /home/user/test/turnon.sh "$line"
done < <(tail -F /home/user/log/test.txt | stdbuf -oL grep -E -A 1 'NDC003|FLC133' | stdbuf -oL grep 'TO.W')
```

There are several difficulties in your construction.

- The while loop is feeded with a stream, so I found the solution: `done < <( echo hello)`
- The command `tail -F` waits for following lines so you had to ask for special buffering with `stdbuf -oL`. The option `-oL` means line by line ; I think it cannot work with option `-o0` : no buffering.
- note to other readers: `grep -E -A 1 'NDC003|FLC133'` means you use Extended Regular Expression (you are looking for NDC003 or FLC133) and it outputs 1 more line After the matching pattern.
- For each matching line, the ssh command is launched. The script is local, but it will be executed on remote host. The command for bash is read from stdin (`bash -s`).
- I have added the "$line" as a list of arguments for your script. This is for **illustration**. Note that the parsing of arguments is not preserved in the process.